# Magento 2: Why some images aren't showing in Luma theme product page?

Tags: magento2, product-images, luma-theme, media-images

I've installed a Luma theme on my local and it is ok but when I open product page the images not showing.

The console gives errors like this:

```
GET http://localhost/m-2/pub/media/catalog/product//cache/f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/m/j/mj12-orange_main.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands on the root of your installation:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage deploy:mode:set developer;
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:static-content:deploy;
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: How can I use this commands for windows?